# PySpark 1 missing argument 'y'

Tags: lambda, pyspark, arguments

Jupyter PySpark sends the error => TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

I'm working with PySpark in Jupyter, and have the following code, that sends me the below error:

```
l = [i for i in range (0,3000)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
```

```
def check(x,y,k):
    if (((2*x+1)**2)+((2*y+1)**2))<(2*k)**2:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

```
rdd4 = rdd.cartesian(rdd)
```

```
rdd5 = rdd4.map(lambda x,y:(x,y,check(x,y,6)))
rdd5.take(3)
```

and the error is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-137-bee42ddad082> in <module>
      1 rdd5 = rdd4.map(lambda x,y:(x,y,check(x,y,6)))
----> 2 rdd5.take(3)

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in take(self, num)
   1358 
   1359             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 1360             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   1361 
   1362             items += res

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
   1067         # SparkContext#runJob.
   1068         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
-> 1069         sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
   1070         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
   1071 

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 92.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 92.0 (TID 126, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 393, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1354, in takeUpToNumLeft
    yield next(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

the expected result, is to have list of triples (x,y,1 or 0 (depending on the function result))

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your help in this issue !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python lambda function can't unpack a tuple parameter into two arguments:

```
rdd5 = rdd4.map(lambda x, y:(x, y, check(x,y,6)))
```

should be rewritten as:

```
rdd5 = rdd4.map(lambda t: (t[0], t[1], check(t[0], t[1], 6)))

print(rdd5.take(3))
# [(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 1)]
```